# Find all files with a Python Shebang

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, search

I'm trying to run a PEP8 check against a large source tree. The tree is comprised of a mix of files in various languages. The idea is to check all the Python scripts without having to explicitly list them. The majority of these files don't actually have a `.py` extension. Is there a simple way to find all files with the word Python in the shebang or find all files that would be run with Python when executed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
grep -rl '^#!/.*python' .
```

Same thing with [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) :

```
ack -rl '^#!/.*python' .
```

Comment: Note that while `grep -l` would stop reading a file as soon as it finds a match, for files with no match, it would read the whole file. It would also find matches in the middle of files, so for instance it could match on a `shar` file that contains python scripts.

Answer (score 18):

With GNU, or FreeBSD or NetBSD or OpenBSD (and potentially others) `awk`:

```
find . -type f -exec awk '
  /^#!.*python/{print FILENAME}
  {nextfile}' {} +
```

Would look only at the first line of each file and would run as few `awk`s as necessary.

The `nextfile` statement above is not standard but is found in a few implementations including the GNU one (which is probably where it originated from).

While the code above would appear to work in other implementations as well, the `nextfile` statement would not do anything there (would be recognised as an expression consisting in an unset `nextfile` variable), so that would mean all the files would be read fully and the filename would be printed for every matching line.

If your `awk` supports `FNR` (like POSIX awks  do but not the original `awk`, so on Solaris `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` and not `/usr/bin/awk`) and not `nextfile`, you can write  it:

```
find . -type f -exec awk 'FNR == 1 && /^#!.*python/{print FILENAME}' {} +
```

Which would still run as few `awk`s as possible but  would read the files fully.

Another alternative to avoid reading the files fully and that would work with every `awk` and `find` but would mean running one `awk` per file would be:

```
find . -type f -exec awk '
  /^#!.*python/{r=1};{exit}
  END {exit(1-r)}' {} \; -print
```

Comment: +1, but the last command matches empty files as well.

Comment: Good point @l0b0. Updated.